# Getting "ReferenceError: Cannot access 'data' before initialization" with deployment on Vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

My project works fine locally, and i was able to deploy initially. But one i tried to implement a dynamic routing, its giving me errors.

Here's a deployment Pic Error

[seems im not allowed to put a picture...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StA4p.jpg)
But Please Click<<

Anyway heres the error on TEXT

info  - Generating static pages (2/11)
Error occurred prerendering page "/medicine/paracetamol-50mg". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'data' before initialization

I'm not enough smart or well versed to see my error. any help will be appreciated!!

PS: i tried reading that link https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error  i just dont understand what i did wrong as mentioned...

i tried to initialize the variable but with const Data = data < which get imported locally from "../utils/data"

Here's the dynamic page code

```
import React from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import data from "../../utils/data";
import style from "../../styles/medicine.module.css";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";

const Data = data; <<< TRIED ADDING THIS LINE, BUT THE ERROR PERSISTS..

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const paths = Data.medicine.map((x) => {
    return {
      params: { slug: x.slug },
    };
  });

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
};

export const getStaticProps = async (ctx) => {
  const slug = ctx.params.id;
  const data = data.medicine[slug];

  return {
    props: { medicine: data },
  };
};
function MedicineInfo({ medicine }) {
  // const router = useRouter();
  // const { slug } = router.query;
  // const medicine = data.medicine.find((e) => e.slug === slug);
  // console.log(medicine);
  // const ids = data.medicine.map((x) => console.log(x.slug));
  return (
    <div className={style.main}>
      <Head>
        <title>{medicine.name} | Med Office</title>
        <meta name="description" content={medicine.desc}></meta>
        <meta itemprop="name" content={medicine.name} />

        <meta itemprop="image" content={medicine.imgLink} />
      </Head>
      <header className={style.medHeader}>
        <h5>Med Description</h5>
        {/* put #meds on href to get to med section */}
        <Link href="/lobby">
          <a>
            <Image
              src="/icons/backIcon.png"
              width={50}
              height={50}
              alt="backBtnIcon"
            />
          </a>
        </Link>
      </header>
      <div className={style.container}>
        <div className={style.imgContainer}>
          <Image
            src={medicine.imgLink}
            height={110}
            width={120}
            layout="fixed"
            alt={medicine.name}
          />
        </div>

        <h1>{medicine.name}</h1>
        <p>{medicine.desc}</p>

        <h4>
          Costo: <span>{medicine.price}</span>{" "}
        </h4>
        <h5>
          Hecho Por <br></br>{" "}
          <span style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
            {medicine.laboratory}{" "}
            <Image
              src="/icons/certifiedIcon.png"
              width={15}
              height={15}
              alt="verificado"
            />{" "}
          </span>{" "}
        </h5>
        {/* <section className={style.specTable}>
          <h2>Util Para</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
          </ul>
          <h2>Requiere</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
          </ul>
        </section> */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MedicineInfo;
```

Comment: How is your dynamic page file called: `[slug].js` or `[id].js`? Note that you are trying to access `ctx.params.id` in `getStaticProps` when it should be (from what I can see): `ctx.params.slug`.

Comment: Also, you should rename `data` variable in `getStaticProps` to something else like `medicine` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Was trying to comment, but code formatting is important*

Maybe getStaticPath is working fine, since it's actually trying to render the page on a valid path (e.g. /medicine/paracetamol-50mg)

Isnt the getStaticProps the problem?

```js
export const getStaticProps = async (ctx) => {
  const slug = ctx.params.id;
  const data = data.medicine[slug]; // <- Ambigous data?

  return {
    props: { medicine: data }, // Which data?
  };
};
```

Maybe renaming the identifiers could help